# CloudWatch dashboard for notebook instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

In Amazon SageMaker we can see all the notebook instances and details as below.
[image]

I want to get these details into a CloudWatch dashboard. Is there a possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

By default resource utilization for Notebook instances are not emitted to CloudWatch. You can configure it by following the steps here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sagemaker-resource-utilization